# How to list multiple field matches from a single table in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

```
create table Likes(ID1 number(5), ID2 number(5));
insert into Likes values(1689, 1709);
insert into Likes values(1709, 1689);
insert into Likes values(1782, 1709);
insert into Likes values(1911, 1247);
insert into Likes values(1247, 1468);
insert into Likes values(1641, 1468);
insert into Likes values(1316, 1304);
insert into Likes values(1501, 1934);
insert into Likes values(1934, 1501);
insert into Likes values(1025, 1101);
```

The table contains the 'likes' of users identified by their IDs. Liking is a one way connection (If ID1 likes ID2 does not mean that TD2 is liking ID1).

I want to find those IDs, where is a two way connection (where the 'liker' is 'liked back' by user he likes).

I am beginner with Oracle SQL, I hope my question isn't that banal...

Comment: Is there a solution where the "like-connection" are not duplicated in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a join:

```
SELECT t.id1,t.id2
FROM Likes t
INNER JOIN Likes s
 ON(t.id1 = s.id2 and t.id2 = s.id1)
```

Or with EXISTS()

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Likes t
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 FROM Likes s
             WHERE t.id1 = s.id2
                 AND t.id2 = s.id1)
```

Comment: No problem m8 @dsz36

Answer (score 3):

You need to pick a given record id1=X, id2=Y only in a case when another record exists in the table, 
which has id1=Y, id2=X.
A condition like this can be expressed in SQL with the help of EXISTS operator and a dependent subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM likes t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM likes t1
   WHERE t.id1 = t1.id2 AND t.id2 = t1.id1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I watched, read and tried 3 tutorials, i missed the EXISTS() command somehow.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
with tab as (select id1, id2 from Likes)
select id1, id2 from tab
intersect
select id2, id1 from tab;
```

It should perform better, becuase it'll read `Likes` table only once

Comment: Special thanks for this 3th solution! I learned an other new thing!

Comment: always happy to help

Answer (score 3):

Use this query:

```
     SELECT
            id1, id2 from Likes L1
        INNER JOIN (
          Select id1, id2 from Likes
        ) as L2
        on (L1.id1 = L2.id)
WHERE L1.id2 = L2.id1
```